# Why Oracle Specification does not tell anything about metaspace?

Tags: java, jvm, permgen, metaspace

We all know that since Java 1.8 PermGen was removed and replaced by Metaspace.

I have read a lot of topics about Metaspace and I am completely sure that it's exists, but today I was asked about the reference to Oracle JVM specification where is said about metaspace but using search for all the spec I have not find any match for word "metaspace".

Can someone share a link to this information with me or tell why I didn't find any info about it?
https://u13831699.ct.sendgrid.net/ls/click?upn=uvt7rQO8Ptvu-2B8hr9RMS5fH-2FNP6DkmoL4CYkMe-2FSSn4-3Dw6tp_KHSll5rOC-2B1S2wQWe0nP-2FIhkravvodBKAjLnih-2F698V3J78Iu7GL6p-2FlrmT6EpJuZE1QjZS1z9DqBUfYXUfjvnsy4WpgSla5uREbboH11eB9xf4RFjTO5aaC-2F5DLuJE371qIPam0Zq3jA15qfWnRd80epgPQjiG-2BzeXhiJSfP9RIOJg35GegDITWQt1noUni-2FLu5XMMRaphUkzzTawMEXGJxo73SFD4Ub6TWQpH7reRc53nYr2jo-2Fl6h0kLcvWoNFoX7N5-2FrNmNM5-2FK41YeIjSjq4BZOyKqYZ1HKn4YqFOfe3EoK6qk6lefF8uUpdUHik-2BUBRC7CpHGIbIyyBW0jqgNl12ugKAQoCirxitSCvF5-2BYsh3YtPjKlmlhJwJAz4Z

```
======= flowable - license =======
Licensee = riznyk.oleksandr.k@gmail.com
Primary Contact = Oleksandr Riznyk
Issue Date = 2022-12-19

Product = Flowable Design
Version = 3
Expiry Date = 2023-01-19
Type = Trial License

Product = Flowable Platform
Version = 3
Expiry Date = 2023-01-19
Type = Trial License

Product = Flowable Work
Version = 3
Expiry Date = 2023-01-19
Type = Trial License

Product = Flowable Engage
Version = 3
Expiry Date = 2023-01-19
Type = Trial License

Product = Flowable Inspect
Version = 3
Expiry Date = 2023-01-19
Type = Trial License
======= flowable - license =======
Ndei9ovkXcSnMN7GURWeowfJ4Ta4w7n72SEtPUBjv3/XIxDXR5x6i0BfJ5Vf6A72
1+M9Yi9uD8R8Yf+2KOYLWIPtFBXOzFLeURRLRMOyCa3tTJCTNjYPQ7kfyXVcxwIn
nMaQLb1XtC4V9WywVmrxwM18XcNBzDAgpxETBs+NSQMyTcAg+z0XdQdhn3a5YzHA
hIyAvTQSm0kLctU/l/o2yAh66eKEAgV3YAJ711tpU07Ze8iEBA/xLj/UhvydJCx4
Xa2HaIHasXfCRph7CC4mcwEiYN7kmGo5Oe9UaRLfPpEo5z3yhBS6KCNzoanJSyqp
7hI+B+ZSrBkGf3B7E1nZXw==
```

Comment: There never was a “PermGen” in the older specification either. The only defined terms are “stack” and “heap” and even their definition is fuzzier than what the average developer has in mind (because they too often compare with other language’s meaning of these terms).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's an implementation detail of [HotSpot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotSpot), not something that is or should be in the specification of a generic [JVM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/index.html).

You can see it described in [JEP 122: Remove the Permanent Generation](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/122) and some issues linked from it [JDK-8046112](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8046112), [JDK-6964458](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6964458).

Answer (score -1):

JVM specification describe method area.
For example, method area looks like interface,metaspace looks like the implemention.
So you cann't find any match for word "metaspace" in JVM specification.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).